# Arriving in Vienna the night before visa validity begin

Tags: visas, schengen, tickets, austria, qatar-airways

I am planning to travel to Vienna on 13th August from Vietnam with Qatar Airways and expect to arrive in Vienna at 20:25. However, my visa is only valid from 14th August. So will this prevent me from boarding and entering the country? I have tried contacting the airline regarding this issue but haven't been able to get in touch with them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have seen that post, yet I don't know if the answers could be applied to my case, which is in Vienna.

Comment: The answer is the same.  The airline will not let you board the plane.

Comment: @jxgh The answer is the same for all destinations.

Comment: I think you could buy a cheapest throwaway ticket from Vienna to any country outside of Schengen on 14th, claim that you will transfer to this flight via airside. Then you will be let into waiting area for transit passengers, and then you can decide that you actually don't want to go there (possible refunding some money, entering the EU on the 14th). Only works with reasonably large airports, but Vienna is likely such.